# How to assign a unique ID to each corresponding unique column value?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, uniqueidentifier

Imagine a dataframe like shown below:

```
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+---+
|address|lastname|firstname|patientid|policyno|visitid          |id |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+---+
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_1| 1 |
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_2| 1 |
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_3| 1 |
|addr2  |Dobs    |Aliya    |patid2   |policy2 |visituid_aliya_1 | 2 |
|addr2  |Dobs    |Aliya    |patid2   |policy2 |visituid_aliya_2 | 2 |
|addr2  |Dobs    |OP       |patid3   |policy3 |visituid_OP_1    | 3 |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+---+
```

The column value for "id" remains the same when the Name (`firstname` + `lastname`) is same, when the Name becomes different - I want to assign a new id.

I need this because I want to de identify a certain dataset (which contains sensitive details) so that I could use the same data but with changed values, with my application. The field `id` would be used as an index key for joining with other dataframes.

Another part about the `id` is that the other dummy data frames will also contain a similar `id` column which probably would be populated using  the `monotonically_increasing_id()` so it would be better to have the `id` starting from 0 OR 1, in continuously increasing fashion.

How can I go about achieving this in spark with scala?

Comment: You could create an UDF which accepts the two columns (lastname, firstname) and calculates an unique ID (e.g. via hash).

Comment: HI @Blobonat thanks for the UDF idea. Although I didn't mention it in my post but It did cross my mind. If there is some standard function available to do such a thing - that would be great. If not - I guess UDF would be the way to go.

Comment: I have updated solution below check & accept or upvote if it helps .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window` functions.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+
|address|lastname|firstname|patientid|policyno|visitid          |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_1|
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_2|
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_3|
|addr2  |Dobs    |Aliya    |patid2   |policy2 |visituid_aliya_1 |
|addr2  |Dobs    |Aliya    |patid2   |policy2 |visituid_aliya_2 |
|addr2  |Dobs    |OP       |patid3   |policy3 |visituid_OP_1    |
|addr4  |AN      |OTHER    |patid4   |policy4 |visituid_OP_1    |
|addr2  |ANO     |THER     |patid5   |policy5 |visituid_OP_1    |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+
```

```
val expr = Seq("lastname","firstname")
            .map(c => hash(col(c)).as(c))
            .reduce(concat(_,_).asc)
```

```
val winSpec = dense_rank()
                .over(Window.orderBy(expr))
```

Output

```
scala> df.withColumn("id",winSpec).show(false)

+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+---+
|address|lastname|firstname|patientid|policyno|visitid          |id |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+---+
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_1|1  |
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_2|1  |
|addr1  |Pits    |Rodney   |patid1   |policy1 |visituid_rodney_3|1  |
|addr4  |AN      |OTHER    |patid4   |policy4 |visituid_OP_1    |2  |
|addr2  |Dobs    |OP       |patid3   |policy3 |visituid_OP_1    |3  |
|addr2  |Dobs    |Aliya    |patid2   |policy2 |visituid_aliya_1 |4  |
|addr2  |Dobs    |Aliya    |patid2   |policy2 |visituid_aliya_2 |4  |
|addr2  |ANO     |THER     |patid5   |policy5 |visituid_OP_1    |5  |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+---+
```

Comment: I am interested in if others will see this. It's convoluted and not the use of dense_rank. Also look at the AN OTHER vs ANO THER name.

Comment: @thebluephantom - your point about AN OTHER vs  ANO THER is correct. Agreed on that.

Comment: @thebluephantom, Thanks.. Now i have fixed that issue.

Comment: Hi @Srinivas: I have accepted this as my answer because it creates id from 1 (although 0 would be preferred in my case). Thank you for your time, knowledge and effort. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("Xxx", "yyy"),
  ("xxx", "yyy"),
  ("aaa", "yyy")
)).toDF("c1", "c2")

df.withColumn("hashName", hash(concat($"c1", $"c2")))//.show(false)
```

So what are obvious improvements? Separator character between both and upper- or lowercase before the hash. 
And if not cleaned replace all spaces and odd characters with separator.

So better is:

```
df.withColumn("preHashName", lower(trim(concat($"c1", lit("|"), $"c2"))))
  .withColumn("hashName", hash(lower(concat($"c1", lit("|"), $"c2")))).show(false)
```

Not doing this means that in the other answer AN OTHER can be the same as ANO THER in terms of hashing.

Output:

```
+---+------+-----------+-----------+
|c1 |c2    |preHashName|hashName   |
+---+------+-----------+-----------+
|Xxx|y yy  |xxx|y yy   |907198499  |
|xxx|yyy   |xxx|yyy    |-1167597858|
|aaa|yyy   |aaa|yyy    |495090835  |
+---+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your attempt to provide a solution. It was quite intriguing. And I have learnt many things from your post and comments. But this didn't help me solve my problem as after the edit - I clearly mentioned that I need to join my prepared df (with new IDs) with more DFs, which have IDs starting from 0 - so in this case I won't be able to join them using the populated IDs. Once again, thank you for your time and effort. I really appreciate that.